# paged scrollView with labels

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uiscrollview

I'm trying to create a scrollView where u scroll between different labels. As an illustration i have this image:

[image]

I want to make the bottom scrollView i've tried creating a replicate, but in my case it is only adding "Book" to the scrollView and how can i make a smaller spacing between the labels. because in my code there are one label per self.view.frame.width

```
categoryArray = NSArray(objects: "Book", "Elektronik")

var textWidth = 0

for val in categoryArray!
{
    var textLabel: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, CGFloat(textWidth), categoryScrollView!.frame.width, categoryScrollView!.frame.height))
    textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    textLabel.text = val as NSString
    categoryScrollView?.addSubview(textLabel)

    textWidth = textWidth + Int(textLabel.frame.size.width)

    if textWidth > Int(self.view.frame.width) {
        categoryScrollView?.contentSize = CGSizeMake(CGFloat(textWidth), categoryScrollView!.frame.height);

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't read swift very well, but it looks to me like the code is advancing the y position of the label frame on each iteration, rather than the x.  In other words, change:

```
CGRectMake(0, CGFloat(textWidth), categoryScrollView!.frame.width, categoryScrollView!.frame.height)
```

to:

```
CGRectMake(CGFloat(textWidth), 0, categoryScrollView!.frame.width, categoryScrollView!.frame.height))
```